# designing web pages in this style is it bad?

Tags: html, css

creating a html page like these is a bad style ?

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <!--some script goes here-->
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id ="body" style="width:1000px">
  <!-- now all stuff is done here-->
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I was just wrapping all the tags of the `body` into wrapper `#body`. Because when I minimize my browser window, The page is getting up side down and my page also involves stuff like `float:left` and `float:right` and some times tables. Even though I dont use float properties or tables, the words are getting rearranged when I minimized my browser window

When i starting use `<div style="width:1000px">` the elements were still at their same position even though I minimized the browser window. So I was using the div tag right from the start of body to end of it to wrap up all body elements into one. I was using just for width size

I wonder is this a bad style of designing? if it is then how do i stop web page from rearranging when i minimize browser window or when monitor size is too small to handle.

Comment: Nothing wrong with having a wrapper with a fixed width I guess...

Comment: You can set the width on the `<body>`, you know...

Comment: Yes i know we can do it @matt, but is this bad style of designing ? can i create my pages in these way ?

Comment: could anyone tell me is this good or bad so that i can move on with creating my web pages

Comment: @niko Ofcourse you can - if that is the desired behaviour you want there is nothing wrong with it. Maybe rename id="body" to class="wrapper" if you really want to be picky. Just note that the standard size width for a webpage is still around 960px due to screen resolution.

Comment: Fixed-width centered div is an extremely common practice, even stackoverflow uses it. I'd recommend one of the standard widths, 900px or 960px, rather than 1000px. (Also, not really a programming question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want your page to be 1000px wide whatever the browser, it's OK. If you intend your page to degrade/resize/rearrange gracefully on smaller devices (phones, tablets, etc...) then it's obviously not. Simple as that.

However, designing a page to degarde gracefully requires work from the ground up : layout, stretching, menus disappearing, etc... it's not just a matter of everything working automagically.

Last point, instead of your own wrapper, I would suggest you go with a CSS grid or another (eg http://960.gs/), then first use a single row and a full width div. Then, as dev goes by, you might find yourself using more and more the grid to layout page elements, because it's simple, elegant and visually appealing. And the more your page will rely on the grid, the more it will be resizable.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at http://www.digital-web.com/extras/positioning_101/css_positioning_example.php as it covers most of the basics for positioning html elements.

From a semantic point of view I would not reuse words such as 'body' in an element id as it's unnecessarily confusing especially when writing CSS or JavaScript relating to it. Most English speakers tend to call the main page div 'container' or similar to differentiate, but if English isn't your first language then use whatever makes it easier for you to understand.